# how to capture a video with four channels (RGB-IR) in open cv?

Tags: python, opencv

Does anybody know how to use four channels in open cv. I have this rgb-ir camera from e con systems (See3CAM_CU40) and I tried to write the code like below in the usual way. It gives just a complete black video. I guess this is because opencv is originally asking for gbr. But I don't know what to do when the video feed has 4 channels.

```
import cv2
def main():

     windowName1 =" LIve video Feed"

     cv2.namedWindow(windowName1)

     cap=cv2.VideoCapture(1) 
     # cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,-1)
     cap.set(cv2.CAP_FFMPEG,True)
     cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,30)

     if cap.isOpened():
         ret,frame = cap.read()

     else:
         ret=False
     while ret:
         ret,frame =cap.read()
    #     r,g,b =cv2.split(frame)
    #     output = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


         cv2.imshow(windowName1,frame)
         if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
             break

     #cv2.destroyWindow(windowName)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()


     cap.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Check for the frame, if it is empty, the read failed. If not, the API might not be supported by OCV. The latter might be more likely. In that case you would have to install API for you camera and create a wrapper which would convert the raw data from camera to the `cv::Mat`

Comment: HI @Croolman, thank you very much. I have searched in the website of the camera provider. They provide some source code and header files, but all are in C. I have developed my code in python and don't really want to switch into C. So right now I don't know how to convert code lines such as follow to python.       #include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"       Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution from this link.  https://gist.github.com/bhive01/7700bb119150214682b51ade25e121e9#file-see3cam_good_np_slicing-py  See3cam doesn't provide any guide about using it on python.  I hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the below conversion to split RGB and IR separatly. Also you need to set the VideoCapture_Object.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, false); after open the video node
to get the raw Y16 image OpenCV 3.3 and above version. In below OpenCV 3.3 verion Y16 not support by default.

/***************************************************************************/
//Convert to 8 Bit:
//Scale the 10 Bit (1024) Pixels into 8 Bit(255) (255/1024)= 0.249023
convertScaleAbs(InputImage, BayerFrame8, 0.249023);

//Filling the missing G -channel bayer data
ConvertRGIR2RGGB(BayerFrame8, BayerFrame8, IRImage);

//Actual Bayer format BG but Opencv uses BGR & Not RGB So taking RG Bayer format
cvtColor(BayerFrame8, BGRImage, COLOR_BayerRG2BGR);

namedWindow("Camera BGR Frame", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Camera BGR Frame", BGRImage);

namedWindow("Camera IR Frame", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Camera IR Frame", IRImage);

/*****************************************************************************/

// Actual Data format BGIRR after conversion BGGR - IR is replaced with the G 
//IR data is collected as a separate image
bool ConvertRGIR2RGGB(Mat BayerRGIR, Mat &BayerRGGB, Mat &IRimage)
{
//Result image after replacing the IR pixel with the G data
BayerRGGB = BayerRGIR.clone();

//IR data will be half the size of Bayer Image
IRimage = Mat(BayerRGIR.size().height / 2, BayerRGIR.size().width / 2, CV_8UC1);

//copying the IR data and replacing the IR data with G
for (int Row = 0; Row < BayerRGIR.rows; Row += 2)
{
for (int Col = 0; Col < BayerRGIR.cols; Col += 2)
{
//Set the IR Data with Nearby Green 
BayerRGGB.at(Row + 1, Col) = BayerRGIR.at(Row, Col + 1);
//Set the IR Data 
IRimage.at(Row / 2, Col / 2) = BayerRGIR.at(Row + 1, Col);
}
}

return true;
}
/********************************************************************************/